# magento: show Transaction ID in payment table on admin panel

Tags: magento, transactions

i have problem in show Transaction ID to admin , i try to add transaction id to order with this code :

```
$_order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId); 
$payment = $_order->getPayment(); 
$payment = $order->getPayment();
$payment->setTransactionId($yoursetTransactionId)
        ->setCurrencyCode($order->getBaseCurrencyCode())
        ->setPreparedMessage($youcomment)
        ->setParentTransactionId($yoursetTransactionId)
        ->setShouldCloseParentTransaction(true)
        ->setIsTransactionClosed(0)
        ->registerCaptureNotification($BaseGrandtotal);
$order->save();
```

but when i try to see result in orders page in admin panel it`s only added to comment history! how can i add transaction id to payment table ?